# I don't know how to create a Two Column Layout

Tags: html, css

I tried to use a two column layout, except I need both columns to stretch to the bottom. The layout is as specified:

[---HEADER---]

[ROW1][Row2]

[ROW1][Row2]

[ROW1][Row2]

etc etc... (goes to the bottom of the page)

I've searched all over the internet, but I can't find anything that would work for me.

It has to be 2 columns, one that is a fixed size, another that fills the rest of the screen (horizontally) and both have to be different colors and both have to stretch to the bottom. If I put content in them, they shouldn't overflow out of themselves.

And my code is:

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.hb {
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
  width: 100%;
}

.hb-header {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.roboto-slab {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.navbutton {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 2px;
  float: left;
}

.navbutton:link, .navbutton:visited {
  background-color: #00bc00;
}

.navbutton:active {
  background-color: #007200;
}

.chat-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.server-list {
  background-color: #b2b2b2;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50%;
}

.server-chat {
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hb">
  <h2 class="hb-header">Header</h2>
</div>
<div class="chat-content">
  <div class="server-list" id="serverlist">
    <h1>Display Text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="server-chat" id="serverchat">
    <h1>Display Text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see what your problem is. Your code snippet looks fine for the 1st row. What are you asking help for?

Comment: I need both boxes to stretch to the bottom! Read my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use Flex for this layout:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh; /* this will make body take full height screen */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}

.container {
  flex: 1; /* this will make content to stretch to bottom */
  display: flex;
}

.col1 {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.col2 {
  flex: 1; /* this will make content to take remaining space horizontally */
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<header> header</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col1">
    this column has a fixed width of 200px; and will stretch to the bottom
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    this column will take the remaining width and will also stretch to the bottom
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS grid, you can accomplish a layout like you described quite easily.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr; /* left column is fixed, right fills remaining */
  grid-column-gap: 1rem; /* small gap between the columns */
}

header {
  grid-column: span 2; /* header should be full width */
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #eee;
}

section.left {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>header</header>
  <section class='left'>
    left column
  </section>
  <section>
    right column
    <br><br><br><br><br>
    left column is same height as this
  </section>
</body>
```

Your question isn't 100% clear; if you wanted to have rows as well (so as to alternate the content `LRLRLR`), you could use flexbox with odd items having a fixed width, even items being `flex: 1`.